# How to prevent click event to load when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just need a quick help (thanks in advance).
I have a simple clkick event (see below)

```
document.documentElement.className = 'js';
//add the jQuery click/show/hide behaviours:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reply").click(function() {
    if ($("#list1").is(":visible")) {
      $("#list1").hide();
    } else {
      $("#list1").show();
    }
    //don't follow the link (optional, seen as the link is just an anchor)
    return false;
  });
});
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="form-row" id="living">
  <span><a class="reply2" href="#list2">Dining Room</a></span>
  <label id="list2">
    <span>Dining Table - 6 persons</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
    <br />
    <span>Dining Table - 8/10 persons</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
    <br />
    <span>Dining Chairs</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
    <br />
    <span>Cabinet Dresser</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
    <br />
    <span>Display Unit</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
    <br />
    <span>Rug</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
  </label>
</div>
```

My question is: How can I prevent my Jquery to load when I refresh the page, as it displays the checklist tag, when page is loaded.
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution (use preventDefault()):

```
document.documentElement.className = 'js';
//add the jQuery click/show/hide behaviours:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".reply").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#list1").is(":visible")) {
      $("#list1").hide();
    } else {
      $("#list1").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Now your links will not direct you to hashtags.
Changes:
Just add "e" to .click(function(**e**)) and then use method of "e" - e.**preventDefault()**;

Comment: Thanks Demid for your support, but unfortunately it didn't work. The e.preventDefault(); did not work in my code. is there anything else I could do in order to prevent jquery to load when refreshing page?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to prevent Jquery from loading... all what you want, if i understand you correctly, is to hide the checklist on load (initial). You can do this with some CSS:

```
#list1 {
    display : none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".reply").click(function () {
    if ($("#list1").is(":visible")) {
      $("#list1").hide();
    } else {
      $("#list1").show();
    }
    //don't follow the link (optional, seen as the link is just an anchor)
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#list1 {
  display : none;
}
</style>
    <div class="form-row" id="living">
      <span><a class="reply" href="#list2">Dining Room</a></span>
      <label id="list1">
        <span>Dining Table - 6 persons</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
        <br />
        <span>Dining Table - 8/10 persons</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
        <br />
        <span>Dining Chairs</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
        <br />
        <span>Cabinet Dresser</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
        <br />
        <span>Display Unit</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
        <br />
        <span>Rug</span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Meiko, simple answer straight to the point. Worked for me, thanks again.